# How can I change the ScrollBar Style in a WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I have a style for the WPF Toolkit DataGrid, how can I change the style of the ScrollBar without using the Property="Template"? Is that Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Write a style for ScrollBar, and add it to your app.xaml, don't give it any key(x:Key), it will be applied to all SrollBar instances and that inside DataGrid too.